# DateTimePicker date format

Tags: javascript

I am trying to initialize a datetimepicker with the following :

```
$("#dtp").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm', 
    locale: 'fr', 
    defaultDate: new Date('26/04/2016 00:00'), 
    keepOpen: true
});
```

I get this error on Chrome browser :

```
bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: defaultDate() Could not parse date parameter: 26/04/2016 00:00
```

It is working for Firefox and IE.

Comment: Are you missing a single quote?

Comment: It was a mistake, I had the single quote.

Comment: Have you tried it without the 00:00, and perhaps switching it to 04/26/2016?

Comment: Koen, I changed format to 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm' and it is working but the output is in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format while I would like 'DD/MM/YYYY' format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JavaScript **Date** creates a instance that represents a single moment in time. Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

**Syntax:**

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

> **dateString**-
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in
> a format recognized by the Date.parse() method ([IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and also a [version of ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)).

In your case, the date string *'26/04/2016 00:00'* is not recognized a standard format in **Chrome** JavaScript engine.

For more reference see the link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

*Hope this will help to solve your issue !!*

Comment: Seems to be the answer like I said to Anton.

Answer (score 2):

According to MDN - parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

I suggest to use this style

```
defaultDate: new Date(2016 , 4, 26, 0, 0, 0),
```

As for string representation it should be in RFC2822 or ISO 8601 format according to JS documentation.
For example

```
defaultDate: new Date('2016-04-26T00:00:00')
```